After clone a react-native project running into error FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap
As the title I am running into error

module map file
'/Users/nathannewyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dormlist-cyvkwrbumwvlingrdiyrbmyubizc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap'
not found

Here is my pod file:
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

platform :ios, '14.0'

# Opt into generating module maps for all dependencies
use_modular_headers!

def common_pods
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', :modular_headers => true
end

target 'dormlist' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => false,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  common_pods
end

target 'dormlist-prod' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => false,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  common_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(installer)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end

I tried diffence approach by delete the DerivedData folder and re-install pod again with command
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update

I also modify Build Phase as well

I attached additional screenshots build failed here if anyone needs

So how do I solve this issue, what step I need to take and how do I approach it?
I tried diffence approach by delete the DerivedData folder and re-install pod again with command
I also modify Build Phase in Xcode
modified Podfile back and forth

So I fixed the issue but the build is still failing with error 'jsinspector-modern/InspectorInterfaces.h' file not found Does anyone help any idea how to solve this issue?

how you fixed this issue,
I am stucked here, same issue
